# Featured image/thumbnail fallback placeholder image

Tags: post-thumbnails

I'm currently using the_post_thumbnail(); to display featured images in my pages.

Is it possible to set a fallback placeholder image in the event a featured image hasn't been set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`has_post_thumbnail()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_post_thumbnail) as condition and change output accordingly.

Example from Codex:

```
if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
    the_post_thumbnail();
} else {
    echo '<img src="'.get_bloginfo("template_url").'/images/img-default.png" />';
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to implement this in the functions so it would work for all instances of the `the_post_thumbnail` across the site?

Comment: @Vince Pettit from quick look that should be doable by making use of [`post_thumbnail_html` filter](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.3/wp-includes/post-thumbnail-template.php#L101).

Comment: There is a plugin that does this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/default-featured-image/